# Dulmage-Mendelsohn decomposition in R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to implement *Dulmage-Mendelsohn decomposition* in R, which is also known as *breadth-first search for coarse decomposition* and I want to do this:

```
dulmage_mendelsohn <- function(mat) {...}
dulmage_mendelsohn(mat)
> mat_with_blocks
```

Dulmage-Mendelsoh is widely known in MATLAB an Octave (see, for example, https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dmperm.html) and there are C and C# implementations.

It is by using the `Rcpp::` package that I am trying to use CSparse already existing function `::cs_dmperm` (https://github.com/ibayer/CSparse/blob/master/Source/cs_dmperm.c#L1) and after editing the header in a new cpp file in this way:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cs.h>
```

It returns the error:

```
cs_dmperm.cpp:2:10: fatal error: cs.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <cs.h>
```

This is not really different from the steps described in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3023469

Do you know a workaround to use the C function or an existing implementation? I have user search engines extensively with no result.

Comment: Have you build an Rcpp package with external library depdencies before?  There is a minor learning step, but there are lots of tutorials and answers here.

Comment: Also, CSparse is included in package `Matrix` but I do not know if it exports C-level functions to other packages.

Comment: yes, I've used Rcpp in the past but never with classic C

Comment: To a first approximation, do what package Matrix does:  copy CSparse files into your `src/` directory.

Comment: that's exactly what I did

Comment: even copying all .c files, the error is `1st file on the dir: fatal error: cs.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you also have a file `cs.h` in the directory?  Maybe add `PKG_CFLAGS=-I.` to `src/Makevars` -- no magic here, and nothing Rcpp specific. You are getting hung up on packaging with source basics.  Which is not a small topic -- but again, not a question for the `rcpp` tag yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210258/discussion-between-pachamaltese-and-dirk-eddelbuettel).

Comment: I may not have time for chat but if you construct a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I am sure the rcpp-devel list may be able to help.